# json_decode warning: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, joomla

I get this error and is affecting my modules from working properly. I am not sure how to fix it. Most of the help sites said that they got the error after they upgraded but since I did not upgrade I am not sure why I got this error.

> Error Message:  Warning: Creating default object from empty value in 
>   ..../aac/administrator/components/com_poweradmin/helpers/history.php on line 125.

The below starts from line 116 to 154.

> Line 125: "$listPage->params = (isset($listPage->params)) ? str_replace('&', '&', $listPage->params) : '';"

Codes used:

```
 private static function updateHistoryState($post)
{
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['jsn-poweradmin-list-page']))
        return;

    $listPage = json_decode($_COOKIE['jsn-poweradmin-list-page']);
    if ($listPage == NULL)
        $listPage = json_decode(stripslashes($_COOKIE['jsn-poweradmin-list-page']));

    $listPage->params = (isset($listPage->params)) ? str_replace('&amp;', '&', $listPage->params) : '';
    $id = array();

    if (isset($post['id']) && is_numeric($post['id']))
        $id[] = $post['id'];
    else if (isset($post['id']) && is_array($post['id']))
        $id = array_merge($id, $post['id']);

    if (isset($post['cid']) && is_numeric($post['cid']))
        $id[] = $post['cid'];
    else if (isset($post['cid']) && is_array($post['cid']))
        $id = array_merge($id, $post['cid']);

    $isDelete = (int)preg_match('/\.?(delete|remove|trash)$/i', $post['task']);

    if (count ($id) && (is_numeric($id) || is_array($id))) {
        // Bypass if any of id list is not a number
        if (is_array($id)) {
            foreach ($id as $i) {
                if (!is_numeric($i)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        $dbo = JFactory::getDBO();
        $dbo->setQuery("UPDATE #__jsn_poweradmin_history SET is_deleted={$isDelete} WHERE list_page_params LIKE '{$listPage->params}' AND object_id IN (".implode(',', $id).")");
        @$dbo->query();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an error but a warning.

It appears that JSON you are trying to decode is malformed and that `json_decode` does not manage to return you an object of type `stdClass`. Probably `json_decode` returns NULL.

Basically the warning is about trying to assign a property to a variable has not been initialized as a `stdClass` object.